# Int(2) to 16 bit conversion python

Tags: python, binary, int

I am working with a dataset that has some data stored in the format INT(2). I need to convert this to binary (16 bits) to read the data back in a meaningful manner via python.

I am currently using:

```
format(value, '016b')
```

To convert the int to binary to read the bits back. So I am looking for simple verification that the conversion I am doing is correct given the types I am using (since the output I see doesn't quite align with the expected output in the documentation).

For instance, do these converted values make sense given the description above?

2369  -> 0000100101000001

18767 -> 0100100101001111

Comment: What does `INT(2)` mean? It's presumably defined as part of some network or file format standard, or some software's documentation, or some other language reference, or… something. But there are multiple things with names like that from different places, so we need to know which one you're using. Ideally link and quote the actual documentation.

Comment: Anyway, most things that say they want "16 bits binary" don't want a string of 16 `1` and `0` bytes; they want two bytes. You probably want something like `value.to_bytes(2, 'big', signed=True)` or some other combination of the flags (or `struct.pack('>h', value)` or some other combination of struct flags, if you need Python 2 compatibility).

Comment: The documentation describes it as a 2 byte integer. Furthermore, it is stored in HDF5 format and when examining the data field, I get a look at its metadata which says: 16-bit integer, valid_range (0,32767). I think I do want 16 bits binary in this case, not two bytes as I need to examine the individual bits

Comment: First, put that in the question, not in a comment. Second, while that does already tell us _something_, it doesn’t tell us everything I asked, nor does it tell us enough to solve the problem without some guessing based on what people usually do with HDF5. Also, if you have some code that reads some metadata and does something relevant, show us that code and its output, and where you’re stuck, rather than keeping things vague. See [mcve] and the other help articles about how to write a good question—unfortunately, it really isn’t obvious how to use StackOverflow effectively without the help.

Comment: Also, if what you're trying to do is literally just parse and/or generate some HDF5 data, there are libraries that do all the hard stuff for you. You can, e.g., read a whole HDF5 file into Pandas series and/or dataframes in a one-liner, without having to worry about the gritty details.

Comment: That is alright, the other answer has helped confirm my suspicions.  I know you mean well, but please be careful when answering questions moving forward here as your demeanour was neither helpful nor insightful in this case. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) as a potentially helpful resource moving forward.

Comment: Um… you're commenting on your own question, not on an answer. And there's only one answer here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they do. In fact:

`1x2^0 + 1x2^6 + 1x2^8 + 1x2^11 = 1 + 64 + 256 + 2048 = 2369`

`1x2^0 + 1x2^1 + 1x2^2 + 1x2^3 + 1x2^6 + 1x2^8 + 1x2^11 + 1x2^14 =`
`1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 64 + 256 + 2048 + 16384 = 18767`